# Custom LINQ implementations

Tags: linq

There are many LINQ implementations such as LINQ-to-Flickr. To make something like this, do I make my own custom LINQ provider?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/archive/2007/10/04/writing-custom-linq-provider.aspx) tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Aha. That's the only way.

Hit in google 'write LINQ provider'. There are many tutorials out there.

Start with understanding [what exactly Expression is](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx), how it differs from lambdas and how to work with them.

---

I find [this book](http://books.google.lv/books?id=12HliU9_D_kC&dq=pro+linq&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=lv&ei=aYCXS6X6IYyG-Qb23vGuCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false) quite helpful too (at least - beginning).

Comment: I found that book very useful to, but it contains no information what so ever about building a LINQ provider.

Comment: Yes. It explicitly omits Expression trees part. But in order to understand what they are, one should understand what's beneath. And for that purpose - first chapter (i think it was 1st) is just brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to get started, the best place is looking at the [IQToolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/IQToolkit) on Codeplex.  You'll learn a lot about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you do find you need to build your own then look at [IQToolKit](http://www.codeplex.com/IQToolkit) and the [The Wayward Weblog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/) for a full series on how to do it.